# How are temporary objects stored and handled?

Tags: c++, rvalue

Consider this example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int c = a + b; //where is the value of (a+b) stored?
a = a + b; //how about now?
```

My understanding is that temporary objects are handled like a new local variable, i.e. they go on top of the stack. But in line 3 of my example, will (a+b) directly afterwards be uplifted to c? Or copied? And will it be copied in line 4 to the location of a?

Edit: fixed syntax error. 
And why do I care? Because I am looking for a general answer, e.g. when I do not use int but rather a large object or maybe a wrapper for a heap object.

Comment: Please fix the syntax error on the second declaration of `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Have an upvote.

Comment: Local variables usually don't "go on top of the stack" but are stored in registers. `a + b` is most likely stored directly in the destination register and nowhere else.

Comment: @molbdnilo, thank you! I was not aware. But how is this done when it is a much larger object than int? Also do you have a reference for this? I really would like to read up on it.

Answer (score 4):

C++ compilers are allowed to compile code following the "as-if" rule: that is, the source code you write describes the *intention* of the program, not the compiled code.

As such, a compiler might refactor your code to

```
int b = 10;
int c = 15;
int a = 15;
```

or, depending on any subsequent usage of the variables, it might elide them. Finally, note that a *stack* is an implementation concept not a language concept. Barring a couple of C++ Standard Library functions, the C++ standard itself does not mention a stack at all.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you care? Why should it be stored anywhere? The code

```
a = a + b;
```

will make the compiler create code that behaves as you would expect, in first approximation thats all you need to know. It might be that the intermediate value is stored only in some cpu register, it might be that it is not stored anywhere and it might be that the compiler will do something equivalent to this:

```
int temp = a + b;
a = temp;
```

On the other hand, if you really do care what the compiler does to your code, you need to look at its output. Compilers are rather compilcated beasts and making general assumptions is often wrong. This is an awesome tool to inspect the compiler output: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Typo. Please change `int a = a + b;` to `int c = a + b;`

Comment: @AndreasH. oh right, it was a typo in the question and once that was fixed I messed up mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

For intrinsic types, it does not matter; the observable behavior is easily determined and all sort of optimizations happen.
But in case of UDT's, long story. If the temporary is grabbed by value:

1. Copy elision happens if the object is of copy constructible type and and relocation is found to be avoidable.
2. Move construction happens if the is of moveable type and option 1 is not applicable. In which case the temporary is left in some light weight null state, that will be destructed with low overhead.
3. Copy construction takes place where object is of copy constructible none moveable type and relocation is inevitable. In which case the temporary will be destructed with its original value and probably high overhead.

If the UDT temporary is grabbed by reference, its life time will be extended to the scope of the reference and it will be treated like an ordinary lvalue. No copy/move takes place. And destruction happens when the reference dies.